# How to get only cities in geonames

Tags: geonames

I want to get cities from geonames dump.

I tried to use cities1000 dump, but it includes districts of cities too.  For example there is Bronx in this dump, but the city is only New York.

I tried to select cities from allCountries dump using feature code. But there is no  city code. The city can be PPL, PPLA or other.

What is the algorithm to get the cities only?

Answer (score 2):

You have to filter the entries by "PPL" feature code.

Comment: Not only PPL.   PPLC   - capital, PPLA  - center of region.

Comment: PPL seems to return more than just cities. For example, for the US, filtering by fcode = 'PPL' returns more than 100,000 results.